# Where is the bootstrap file in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

With `ZF1` there was a bootstrap file defined under `application/Bootstrap.php` but I can't find it when looking at the [`ZF2 skeleton application`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication).

**What is the `ZF2`'s equivalent to the `ZF1 Bootstrap.php` file?**

Comment: I've not played with ZF2 yet, but you may want to checkout the event manager (again, just a guess on my part).

Comment: @doydoy44, the new tag name is inappropriate and un-needed.  Questions about ZF1 and ZF2 **should** have both tags.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In ZF2, there is no individual Bootstrap file as there was in ZF1.  You can however, add an `onBootstrap()` method to any of your `Module` classes so it will be called after `loadModule.post` once `$application->bootstrap()` is called.

On github in the ZF2 Skeleton App, the file you would add an `onBootstrap()` method to is located at [module/Application/Module.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/Module.php).

Here is some relevant documentation on Bootstrapping from the ZF2 user guide (note: any of this material is subject to change).

[The MVC Bootstrap Event](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.module-manager.module-class.html#zend.module-manager.module-class.the-mvc-bootstrap-event)
[Bootstrapping an Application](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.mvc.html#zend.mvc.intro.bootstrapping-an-application)
[Bootstapping (in relation to MVC)](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.mvc.examples.html#zend.mvc.examples.bootstrapping)
[Sample usage of the MVC Bootstrap Event](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/zend.module-manager.module-class.html#zend.module-manager.module-class.example.mvc-bootstrap-event)

Answer (score 7):

From Gary Hockin's [nice article](http://blog.hock.in/zf2-for-zf1-users-part-1) about bootstrapping and other changes in ZF2:

> There is no application level bootrapping in Zend Framework 2, each
>   module is responsible for bootstrapping it's own resources in it's
>   `Module.php`. This is done using a combination of the `onBootstrap` method
>   of the module class, and the `Event Manager`. Realistically, most
>   bootstrapping is no longer needed; it's been replaced by entries in
>   the `Service Manager` and event hooks, but as an example, here is how
>   you can perform module level bootstrapping by using the `onBootstrap`
>   method of `Module.php`:

```
public function onBootstrap(\Zend\Mvc\Event $e)
{
    $myService = $e->getApplication()->getServiceLocator()->get('my-service');
    $myService->doBootrappingCode();
}
```